# Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR) Class 'APP\Mail\Reverify' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing an app in PHP Laravel 5. I want to add a reverify function in loginController, I add a Class Reverify Reverify.php in app/Mail, but I got this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR) Class 'APP\Mail\Reverify' not found.

I have done artisan `clear-compiled` and `composer dump-autoload`, it didn't work. And I checked my autoload_classmap.php in vendor/composer, I can see
    `'App\\Mail\\Reverify' => $baseDir` . `'/app/Mail/Reverify.php'`, in there.

here is my **LoginController** code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Mail;
use APP\Mail\Reverify;

class LoginController extends Controller  {

...

...

Mail::to($email)-> send(new Reverify($confirmation_code));

...
...}
```

my **Reverify.php** is in app/Mail

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Reverify extends Mailable
{
    public $confirmation_code;

    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->confirmation_code = $confirmation_code; 
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('XXXX: lock out')->view('reverify');
    }
}
```

my **autoload_classmap.php** is in vendor/composer

```
 'App\\Mail\\Reverify' => $baseDir . '/app/Mail/Reverify.php'
```

Here is my **error log**

```
2019-02-25 02:42:50] local.ERROR: Class 'APP\Mail\Reverify' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'APP\\Mail\\Reverify' not found at /home/vagrant/code/x/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php:207)
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.5.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.1.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Should the namespace be `APP` or `App`?

Comment: @MattKomarnicki Thank you Matt !  I am so stupid ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **LoginController** try changing

`use APP\Mail\Reverify` to  **`use App\Mail\Reverify`**